# Load component on onClick of li in React

Tags: reactjs

In my application, On the launch of the application, I am displaying a character from the provided JSON file.
Upon selecting a character the UI should update and display details on each of the films the character appears in. For that, I have made MovieDetails component which makes API calls ( API URL’s provided in the JSON file and the data returned from those calls ).

I am trying to fetch movie details when user click on first li (Luke Skywalker) for that I am using a switch case in handleClick(). But it's not working. Can anyone suggest me how to update the UI when the user click on li?

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import charactersFile from "./data/characters.json"
import MovieDetails from "./MovieDetails";
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    render: false
  }

  handleClick = (character) => {
    console.log(character.name);
    this.setState({ render: true })
  }
  render() {
    const list = <ul>
      {
        charactersFile.characters.map(character => {
          return <li key={character.name} onClick={() => this.handleClick(character)}>{character.name}</li>
        })
      }
    </ul>
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.state.render ? list : <MovieDetails />}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

MovieDetails.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

class MovieDetails extends Component {
  state = {
    movies: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const PeopleUrl = `https://swapi.co/api/people/`;
    const FilmUrl = `https://swapi.co/api/films/`
      axios.get(`${PeopleUrl}1/`)
      .then(response => Promise.all([
        axios.get(`${FilmUrl}2/`),
        axios.get(`${FilmUrl}6/`),
        axios.get(`${FilmUrl}3/`),
        axios.get(`${FilmUrl}1/`),
        axios.get(`${FilmUrl}7/`)
      ]))
      .then(result => result.map(values =>
        this.setState({
          movies: [
            ...this.state.movies,
            { title: values.data.title, release_date: values.data.release_date }
          ]
        })))
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.title)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ul>
          {this.state.movies.map(movie => (
            <li key={movie.title}>
              {movie.title} - {movie.release_date}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MovieDetails
```

characters.json

```
{
  "characters": [
    {
      "name": "Luke Skywalker",
      "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/1/"
    },
    {
      "name": "C-3PO",
      "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/2/"
    },
    {
      "name": "Leia Organa",
      "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/unknown/"
    },
    {
      "name": "R2-D2",
      "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/3/"
    }
  ]
}
```

output:

[image]

Comment: "It's not working" is never a problem, it's just an opinion: the computer's doing exactly what you told it to do, so it's working exactly as it was programmed to. So here's the real problem: the click handler has to _do_ something, not _return_ something. In the kind of app you're describing, it should be setting the state such that in `render()` there is a way to check that (1) the user has picked a specific person, and (2) who that person is. (which you can probably do with a single state var). The `render` function can then go "ah, I should render `<MovieDetails>`, not the general list".

Comment: I am already generating a list in <MovieDetails>. So it shouldn't display that?

Comment: your `onClick` returns a `<MovieDetails>`, and that makes no sense. `handleClick`  should be calling `this.setState({ ... })` and then `render()` should be looking at `this.state` to decide what it should be rendering

Comment: I updated my answer but still not working correctly.

Comment: I have no idea what you thought your update would do. All you've done is set `state.render=true`, which you then don't even tap into in the `render()` function. Just make it call `this.setState({ character })` and then in render use `render() { if (this.state.character) return renderForCharacter(); return renderRegularPage(); }`

Comment: My problem got solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: React only renders DOM elements inside a render function. If you return a components inside any other functions (in your case you are returning a component inside onClick function) you should not expect react renders a new content or a component.

Right now your `onClick` gets called upon a user's interaction. So you need to tell react to re-render the page and based on the current state renders different contents or components. As you probably know in order for react to `re-render` the page you need to `set the state` so inside your onClick 
 set your state to whatever your logic is `this.setState({ ... })`. Then inside your render function you can check the current state value that you just set inside onClick method whether to display `<MovieDetails />` or something else.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/pr0bwg3L/5/

Comment: I have updated my code but still not getting the desired result

Comment: You are setting your state `true` but in your render function you are returning `list` if this.state.render is `true`. look at the example I added

Comment: Thanks, @Matin for answering my question.